# Where can I travel if I want to see cheetahs?

Tags: where-on-earth, nature-and-wildlife, destinations, africa

My favorite animals are cheetahs. So I would like to see them in the natural habitats. Where should I travel to to maximize my chances?

Comment: Thanks @hippietrail for tagging. But is Africa correct? Or are cheetahs only available in Asia?

Comment: I tagged according to the answers \-:

Comment: Would a cheetah in the wild likely attack a human observer?

Comment: I think cheetahs are opportunistic so if you become sick or tired or lame in there presence might not be the best of all possible circumstances.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this Wikimedia image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cheetah_range.gif) you can find cheetahs around Africa and Middle East.

[image]

<sup>Image is in public domain</sup>

One of the easiest places to see Cheetahs (I saw a lot there) is Masai Mara National Park (Kenya).

Comment: Seconded on Masai Mara.  We saw several there, and a couple in the Serengeti and Ngorongoro as well.

Answer (score 8):

Certainly much of Africa has them in their natural habitat.  Tourist wise, an easy option is a flight to JHB (Johannesburg), and then east a few hours by car to Kruger National Park.  I can personally attest that they are there - I have photos to prove it ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for one single place, go to the [Okonjima](http://www.okonjima.com) Reserve in Namibia. It is located not far from the Waterberg plateau, a four hours drive from Windhoek.

In big reserves like Kruger (South Africa) or Etosha (Namibia) you can travel on your own. Nevertheless, I would rely on the services of a guide if I really wanted to see Cheetahs. Okay, you can find some on your own, it is perfectly possible. Moreover, a guide may fail to find some. That's nature ... However, using professional guidance is an excellent way to maximize your chances.